# Use look-up table in Tag Manager to determine which Analytics Property to post data to, based on URL

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have two websites on the same domain: example.com/fr and example.com/us.  Each website has its own Google Analytics Property.  I'd like to record page view data in each website's respective Analytics property.

Since there may be many more websites and Analytics Properties in future I thought the best way to manage this would be to create a custom variable of type RegEx Table to map Page URLs to Analytics Property Ids, like this:

- `*example\.com/us* maps to: UA-123456789-0`
- `*example\.com/fr* maps to: UA-123456789-1`
- etc

…then use that variable as the value of the 'Google Analytics Settings' field in a new Universal Analytics Tag.  I feel like I've set this up properly but it just will *not* log any data in Analytics whatsoever.  I've tried it with even the loosest RegEx patterns e.g `*example\.com*` and even `*` and still nothing gets into Analytics.

I've tried a similar thing using a Lookup Table (as opposed to a RegEx Table) and that works as expected, but I believe a look-up table is limited to matching only an exact URL, so if I map http://example.com/us/ to UA-123456789-0 (my US site's Analytics Property Id) it works great when I visit that page exactly, but when I visit http://example.com/us/test/ it doesn't log anything as the URL isn't matched exactly in the lookup.  So I know the principle of what I'm doing works with a Lookup Table, but it seems the same approach doesn't work with a RegEx Table.

I wanted to ask:

1. It is possible to use a Regex table for outputting an Analytics Property Id?
2. If so, any pointers as to what I might have done wrong?
3. If not, are there any other neat options?  (Otherwise I'm potentially going to have to set up a lot more variables/events/tags if I need to log the same things on each site to different Analytics Properties - it'd involve adding the same conditions onto pretty much every tag.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your regex looks a bit off. You have a star character for "arbitrary number of characters", but you apply it to the last character of the string (matching "example,com/ussss", but not "example.com/use/path"). You probably want to do ".*" ( the dot is "any character", so ".*" matches any number of any characters.

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff. On modifying the RegEx expressions I'm able to observe some logging in Analytics when using the RegEx Table lookup, so I can conclude that it does in fact work as a principle - it's just my RegEx that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As prompted by the comment from @EikePierstorff, it seems that it *is* possible to use a Regex Table as a lookup for determining the Analytics Property Id to use based on URL.  The simple issue was incorrect RegEx expressions.